# Passing arguments to command line program

Tags: bash

I'm doing math parser where I need to have input through command line.
So I did it but I have problem that bash is giving me error with `-bash: syntax error near unexpected token`('` when I input expression like 3*(2). On normal input it's working.

Comment: Please paste some code

Comment: oh I solve it.. I need it input like '3*(2)' damn

Comment: You should clarify what 'normal input' is (with an example or two).

Comment: It's math parser so my input was like ./myprog 'sin(25) - 3*(35-1)' etc without these ' ' it wasn't working :)

Answer (score 4):

Certain characters such as `*`, `(`, and `)` have special meaning to the shell.  You'll need to escape them with a backslash when calling your program:

```
./myprog 3 \* \( 2 \)
```

Comment: @JakubStibůrek: backslashes or single quotes both work — and the reason is what dbush stated; they have special meanings to the shell.

Comment: Double quotes would probably work too for the kinds of inputs involved, but single quotes are safer.